# Cannot add items to start menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I seem to be completely unable to add items to the start menu in Windows 10.

If I right-click on a folder and choose "Pin to Start" nothing happens.

If I drag and drop an item onto the start menu, nothing happens (screenshot of the icon I see when trying to drag and drop a folder. I drew the red box around the icon of a folder I am trying to drop).

[image]

I have checked to make sure the various "Start Menu" folders have correct permissions. I have even tried creating shortcuts to these items IN the start menu folders. The shortscuts get created, but the items do not show up on the start menu.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You are only suppose to be able to pin to a folder to quick access so that is at least half the problem.

Comment: I've tried it with shortcuts too. (tried it with every kind of file)

Comment: Have you activated windows?

Comment: I having the same problem here.. it seems to be related to amount of apps installed.

Comment: I have got the very same problem. Installers won't create any start menu entries as well. Have you got any solution for this problem by now, @CleverHuman

Comment: I haven't got an answer yet to this issue. But I asked a similar question that might be related that seems to have solved a lot of people's issues (but not mine :-(  ). Give some of the solutions here and it might help you: http://superuser.com/questions/950009/cortana-search-is-not-finding-applications-on-windows-10/950062#950062

Comment: Also, For What It's Worth, after I couldn't solve this issue for a week or more, I started using ClassicShell to replace my start menu. It is an excellent program and has been working so well, I forget I don't have the native start menu anymore: http://www.classicshell.net/

Answer (score 0):

PaulC_1's [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/pin-to-start-any-file-windows-10-pro/acb769bc-e5d9-4be9-8a76-0aff7cdab6c8):

1. Create a shortcut to the item within:

   ```sh
   # Once done, item appears in the list of Start Programs
     %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
   ```
2. Right-click on the item within *Start Programs* and select *Pin to Start*