# Windows 10 Search not working - after privacy tweaks

Tags: windows, windows-10, search-indexing

I installed **Windows 10 enterprise** for about a week,
right after I disabled all the ugly spying stuff!

Now the simple search of it, won't work.

Found thousands of others like myself having similar issues,
some issues were older, on the older releases, 
I'm using the latest **10240** 
In other hand some had AV issues, but I didn't install any security stuff yet! And near all opened topics were still ongoing...

The option for simply disabling defender doesn't work and it keeps re-enabling itself!
Maybe without disabling some privacy stuff the issue happens for other people, or probably they did some similar tasks, I experienced it after disabling these. The search seemed was working randomly and slowly and eventually it becomes dead. really nothing happened against it! As a computer expert and a programmer I can't even guess what the problem might be.
(Sorry that I do not want to re-enable them to see what will happen!, in both sides if they work or not work, it is a shame)

*When you click on the search and try typing it shows that it is thinking and searching but the progress never ends!*

By privacy tweaks I didn't mean I did anything special, I only disabled the options I had: **Cortana!, Windows defender, what I type, report Microsoft, Sharing Location, Search online, Get to know me!, etc.**

Does anybody have a final solution to this?

Someone/"some post" like me: [Windows 10 Search not working](https://superuser.com/questions/955542/windows-10-search-not-working)

Another similar: [Cortana Search is not finding applications on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950009/windows-10-cortana-search-is-not-finding-apps)

Comment to the last link: the original asker told that it isn't solved for him! His comment yesterday on the marked answer:

> Yeah, exactly. I still am having issues with this. At this point I think this is a bug in Windows 10 and will hopefully be fixed as a patch. I may as well mark this as the fix, even though it is not 100%

Windows installation is a routine task for me, so as I said earlier, I didn't still do anything especial on it.

Comment: It's not bugs, it's by design.  You can disable the privacy problems, but that also disables features.  You either play ball or Microsoft takes their ball and goes home.

Comment: I mentioned that as a mental issue of the windows! lol , I see the design like a bug, doesn't differ much.

Comment: The issue is that if you admit that you don't want the extra features! If you ignore """Cortana bringing the world into your hand option!""" the simple search even won't work, which is not what they mentioned.

Comment: Also I should mention that if I used the term buggy, that isn't go just for this issue, the bugs is obvious when you are working the win as a pro, even the explorer keeps hanging in several cases which the tasks were too normal in every other windows versions.

Comment: There have been some articles about the "false advertizing" / "fine print" issue.  Looks like Microsoft took lessons about the wonderful world of data mining from Google and wants a piece of the action.  There's speculation that the value of your personal information is what underwrites the free upgrade.

Comment: I had that idea, IMO also they wanted more data-mining.

Comment: Yet I believe that that was the most awkward move of the Microsoft, In terms of users no body accepted or liked what google is collecting from people day-life activities.

Comment: Most of the experts around me when hearing Microsoft they recall me, because they don't know anyone more based on MS technologies, in every discussions online or offline I was defending Microsoft, now for the first time I downloaded Linux. :D

Comment: I will never use W10 as my everyday PC, will be moving to Linux when W7 dies. Microsoft has gone too far invading everyone's privacy. W10 is nothing more than a spyware OS.

Comment: To correct your sentence, IMO win10 isn't a spyware, it is a buggy operating system, windows way (some upward moves more downward), in addition with spying engine, and a one-side rule giving the MS the ability to observe people day-life activities and worse than that interfere when and how they like.

Comment: Forgot to mention that google also is doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check how many items are in your search index: Right-click start button -> Control Panel -> Indexing Options -> Modify

I found that having a large number (in the hundreds of thousands to millions) of items caused search to run slowly and sometimes fail.

See if my more detailed answer here helps you out: https://superuser.com/a/961511/171407

Comment: sorry but it is far away from being the correct answer.

Comment: No worries, it sounds like there are a few different issues with similar symptoms so it's hard to know what will work for different people. Hope you work out what it is though!

Comment: You are right, though some part of the issue could be related to the design, it is combined with some inner bugs in different levels, also if even possible we are looking for a kind of hack or fix or in other word any solution.