# Windows 10 search not showing as many results?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

For example, Network and Internet are not showing up. Another one is the individual options in Control Panel, such as System, Programs and Features, etc. Also, Device manager is not showing up. Is there any way to get the Windows 10 search to behave more like Windows 7?

More not working: Indexing Options, Sound, Disk Management

Here's a few screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get why someone downvoted my question :/

Comment: Dude you can also look at: http://superuser.com/q/959233/130811 and the linked questions, especially one of them could be useful for you, I hope so.

Comment: Tried everything there... Nothing worked :(

Comment: sorry couldn't help, understand you.

Comment: Did you try modifying search locations in Control Panel>Indexing Options?

Comment: Yep. I included everything and rebuilt the index.

Comment: Try another answer linked in my question, at this link: http://superuser.com/a/956357/130811 , there is a little hope for you :) maybe it helps.

Comment: Tried everything there... :( I ended up going back to Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and found a solution in [this thread](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1267252-windows-10-no-searchresults-from-control-panel-or-settings/?do=findComment&comment=597032734).

In your indexing options (control panel) you have to include the following folder:

`C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState`

Cheers

Comment: I wish I still had Windows 10 to try it, but I downgraded, as I couldn't find any solution for weeks...

Comment: Went to try Windows 10 again, and I tried this. Nope, doesn't work. Windows 10 really needs to get their act together, the start menu lags when pressed, and the search doesn't even work properly. Going back to 7...again... :(

Answer (score 0):

For your information, there are many reasons that could lead to Windows 10 search problems and I faced/tried many. For reading more you can start with this [useful and helpful question and answers.](https://superuser.com/q/947392/735961)

But the one solution and reason for all problems I faced was [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1208858/735961).

***In short:*** *all steps I can imagine would solve the problem are the following:*

1- Run `services.msc` (via Windows + R buttons then type it or via Control Panel) and make sure `Windows Search` is `enabled` and started. You should see the result immediately.

2- Go to `Indexing Options`, chose `Advanced` then choose to 'Rebuild the index'. If this fixes the problem as you say every time then simply try the next suggestions.

3- Go to "Settings". Open "Privacy" settings then click on "Background apps" section. Enable `Let apps run in the background`. Restart your PC.

4- If previous solutions didn't work, you might try this one which is reinstalling Cortana package. Open PowerShell window either by right clicking on the start square icon in the corner then selecting `Windows PowerShell (Admin)` or by running command prompt as administrator then typing `powershell` then Enter.

```
Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

This might result you an error in read color though (I can't post an image right now, sorry). So you might have to end the Cortana process from the task manager and once ended, quickly apply the command. My Cortana process in Windows 10 Creators update could be found in the task manager under the `Details` tab with name `SearchUI.exe` and description `Search and Cortana application`. Of course to end the process, right click and choose `End task`.