# Can't find applications anymore in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In Windows 8.1 I was able to find any application by pressing windows key and starting to type it's name.

After upgrading to Windows 10 I have lost this ability. For example, below is what happening when I am trying to find Kaspersky software:

[image]

[image]

I.e. it looks everywhere, but not in applications.

How to fix/overcome?

Comment: Try some of the solutions here: http://superuser.com/questions/950009/windows-10-cortana-search-is-not-finding-apps