# Start Menu is broken after installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

After installing Windows 10, my Start Menu got totally broken.

Most of the programs and absent in it now. They can't be found neither by search, nor by step-by-step navigation.

Some of programs are substituted for another versions.

Simultaneously, the Start Menu folder is Ok in filesystem.

So my entire Start Menu is useless now.

To run any program, I am opening Far Manager (file manager), opening Start Menu folder in it and doing search for appropriate `*.lnk` file.

I.e. I am doing by hand what Windows should do with it's Start Menu feature.

`*.lnk` files are working fine.

Various aspects of the problem were discussed in questions:

[Where are ALL locations of Start Menu folders in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/960406/where-is-the-location-of-start-menu-folder-in-windows-10)

[How to fix / refresh start menu in Windows 10? How to add / remove / edit items in bulk?](https://superuser.com/questions/957084/how-to-fix-start-menu-in-windows-10-how-to-add-remove-edit-items-from-it)

[Can't find applications anymore in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957036/cant-find-applications-anymore-in-windows-10)

So, please don't suggest primitive solutions, covered there?

Comment: So, since we can't suggest primitive solutions already covered, what exactly is your question (don't be primitive, be specific)? This is written more like a complaint about Windows 10 than anything else.

Comment: This is real problem, I didn't imagine it. You can provide any solution you wish, but most probably they won't work if they straightforward.

Comment: Same problem here, can't seem to find much in the way of other people with this issue. It's hard to describe other than being completely broken - search does not find applications, only files; most applications cannot be pinned at all; many applications cannot be started from All Apps (left or right clicking does nothing); many applications are completely missing from All Apps; Most Used and Recently Installed are both non-functional (Most Used displays a random selection of Metro apps only)