# Where is the Snipping Tool in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, snipping

Where is the [Snipping Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snipping_Tool) in Windows 10?

I can't get it to appear in my start menu when I'm typing its name, like I could before Windows 10.

Is there a built-in **alternative**?

(Of course, we know about <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, that's not the question...)

*After several answers it turns out that the real problem was
that the Windows Indexing Service was turned off to prolongue my SSD's
lifespan (Thanks, Samsung Magician) ...*

Comment: If you unhide hidden folders and system files All the windows tools can be found in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: I had never heard of the snipping tool... interesting I've been using MS Paint for cropping screenshots this whole time.  Can anyone explain what the indexing service has to do with it?

Comment: The is also a new 'Microsoft Garage' snipping tool see link https://mix.office.com/snip

Comment: @Brad Since Win7 I was used to press the Win-Key and then type "Snip" and press enter to start the snipping tool. Now with a fresh install of Windows 10 that workflow from the Startmenu-Search stopped working. I originally thought that the snipping tool had been cut from the OS but really the search was disabled.

Comment: @Brad: The snipping tool, and win-printscreen are awesome.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Win +Printscreen?  That doesn't do anything different than Printscreen on my Windows 7 box.  I usually use Alt + Printscreen to capture the focused window.

Comment: It automatically saves the contents of the current screen(s) in windows 8 and better.

Comment: @KarmaEDV Ah got it.  So, the indexing service has nothing to do with the tool... it's just that you were unable to find it without searching and since the indexing service was off, so was search.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Didn't know of Win+PrintScreen either, nice!

Comment: win + R then type SnippingTool

Comment: Just for reference, consider https://getgreenshot.org/ which has more features and is easy to use.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could just find Snipping Tool from the Start Menu. If you don't find it on the Start Menu, then you should **Rebuild your Index**

To rebuild the Windows Search index, head back to

> Control Panel > Indexing Options

. Click the **Advanced button** and make sure you’re on the **Index Settings** tab of the **Advanced Options** window.

[image]

Comment: Just curious - how did you know that you needed to do that? That seems quite counterintuitive.

Comment: Nope I said from my intuition.

Answer (score 46):

It's `%windir%\system32\SnippingTool.exe`.

Comment: Thank you David, good to know it's still there. I have no idea, why it didn't show up in my Start-Menu even when searching (on two different W10 PC's!)

Comment: Alright, my real problem was that theWindows Indexing Service was turned off to prolongue my SSD's life (Thanks, Samsung Magician) ...

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively if you don't have indexing enabled and don't want to use your mouse..

`Windows Key + R` to show the *run prompt*

then enter `snippingtool` and press *enter*

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't see any using the run prompt, just using the start menu.. which requires indexing to be enabled. My answer doesn't require indexing.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks for clarifying that in your answer.  +1

Answer (score 6):

You can also simply press the <kbd>Start</kbd> button and type `Snip` and it will appear.

[image]

Comment: Seeing how your issue was with the indexing service, this answer is technically correct, but also not as the same time.

Comment: It's actually the prerequisite of the question, since it's how i do it since W7. Somehow a fresh install of W10 on Samsung 850 Pro & Magician Software disables the Indexing Service by default.

Comment: Windows has some issue that it doesn't search sometimes because of cortana issues. Kill Cortana from task manager and you will see snippets in the menu. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-taskbar-search-not-working-windows-10

Answer (score 6):

If you can't or don't want to search the start menu using the search function, or if you want to leave your indexing service disabled, then you can browse to the snipping tool this way:

Start -> All Apps -> Windows Accessories -> Snipping Tool

Answer (score 5):

Snipping tool is still there! To open the Snipping Tool, just type Snipping in the start menu and you can see the desktop app or You can find it by browsing to the below location:

> C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe

Comment: yeah, more likely than not, there's something wrong with the indexing on my machines. "calc" doesnt work from the start menu either ... :(

Comment: You could take a look at the following link if your problem is related to Cortana search. http://superuser.com/questions/950009/windows-10-cortana-search-is-not-finding-apps

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 includes OneNote built in. Win+S is the hotkey for screen clipping and then save it in a notebook or click 'Copy to clipboard'

Comment: Win+S brings up Cortana in Windows 10 for me.

Comment: I think it's Win+Shift+S, if you have OneNote running

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of Cortana for security reasons but I just click "all apps" scroll down to "windows accessories" scroll down to "snipping tool". I would drag it to the task bar for future 1 click access. I was surprised by how much I use it.

Comment: [How to write good answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

As of 1809, "Snipping Tool is moving... In a future update, Snipping Tool will be moving to a new home. Try improved features and snip like usual with Snip & Sketch"