# My cortana is totally messed up what can I do?

Tags: cortana

I want to access control panel.

Simple?

Cortana ask for my address. The problem is it's a desktop PC and there is no easy way for me to set my address. I insert it by name and it simply points to somewhere I don't know.

In any case, I just want to access control panel and this is what I see

Here is another screenshot

[image]

[image]

It stays like that for a very long time.

I don't want top stories for today. I don't want anything FANCY. I just want to access that ******** control panel.

It used to work.

I want simple windows search. Like the run command in windows 7. Now it's gone.

Looks like Cortana tries to display hot news that never finish no matter what I type. How can I get the old normal windows search?

Comment: Have you tried disabling cortana in "Cortana and Search Settings"?  I don't have cortana enabled and am shown the control panel option when I do a search. [link](http://tinypic.com/r/1zwjjie/9)

Comment: There is also another option in "Cortana and Search Settings" called "Search online and include web results", turning this off may help also.

Comment: If you want the control panel then right-click on your Windows Start icon and choose control panel?

Comment: Windows always makes us angry

Comment: You shouldn't have upset Cortana, she has a long memory.

Comment: how do I access cortana and search settings? Oh I get it. Search in cortana. Okay any other ways? @headkase is right. Thanks

Comment: I did what @Mark suggest. It seems that cortana simply cannot find anything anymore. It just show a blank screen

Comment: Doesn't sound like she is happy at all... Perhaps have a look at this thread. [link](http://superuser.com/questions/950009/cortana-search-is-not-finding-applications-on-windows-10)

Comment: reinstalling cortana works

Comment: same issue on my laptop.
when there is no internet connection at startup searchUI just stop returning local search result  :-(
I had to reinstall windows 10.