# Windows 10 Search does not show new applications installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

Windows 10 search stopped showing any of the newer apps that I have installed. I can search for older apps (apps that I have installed prior to May 2017) however any apps that I have installed after that point do not appear in search results. These new apps do appear in the start menu and I can see the lnk file in the following location: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

I have tried the following solutions so far but none have worked:

1. Rebuilding the index cache and running the search troubleshooter.
   [image: Indexing Options]
2. Tried the solution from the accepted answer here: [Cortana Search is not finding applications on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950009/cortana-search-is-not-finding-applications-on-windows-10)

I appreciate any help with this! Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted the service Windows Search ?

Comment: Try to move or copy those shortcuts in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: @LPChip Yes I've tried restarting Windows Search service but it didn't fix the issue. I can still search files on my laptop perfectly. For example, it finds all files/folders in my downloads and documents folders.

Comment: @Biswa I guess that would be a workaround but I was hoping to be able to search the entries in the start menu normally. I can see the programs I have installed in the start menu, it's just when I search for them using Windows Key > search term it doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you updated to the Anniversary/Creator's update?

Comment: @RadialApps Yes I have the creator's update installed. At this point, I'm just going to wait for the next major windows update and if it doesn't fix it I'll do a reformat.

Comment: I did a new Windows 10 install and have this problem. From what i gather from other people solving this problem, i get the impression that it has to do with a privacy / Cortana setting somehow.