# Windows search won’t show installed apps even with indexing allowed

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

I have Windows 10 Pro on my SSD. 
I have turned on the indexing option for the system but turned off Cortana.

When I use “Start” to search for software installed on the system, they don't show up.

[image: windows showing no result]

As you can see, I have Android Studio installed, and it doesn’t show up.

I have the following indexing options:
[image: Indexing options]

How can I find all my files (through search)?

Comment: This might help [Fix: Start Menu Cortana Search Not Finding Apps](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/installed-apps-not-find-start-menu-search-results-background-apps-off/) . See also [Cortana Search is not finding applications on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/950009/cortana-search-is-not-finding-applications-on-windows-10)

Comment: that is why I use [StartIsBack++](https://superuser.com/a/946675/174557)

Comment: @Win32Guy Dunno what but something worked; looks like it wasn't searching start menu within appdata. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is why I use and recommend [Everything](http://voidtools.com/). Because this indexing service just works.

[image: Searching for android exe files with Everything]

Comment: Installed it, will surely try this, but for now got the windows search fixed with the help of @Win32Guy.