# Cortana can't find any third-party apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I recently installed Windows 10 1709, already updated it but Cortana can't find any third-party apps like Firefox. But it can find Windows apps like Calculator and Edge.
Already tried some tips with Powershell but none seems to help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What "tips with powershell" have you tried?

Comment: Thanks :). I saw the PowerShell thing in some questions and articles. They are all similar to this one (The best answer one): https://superuser.com/questions/950009/cortana-search-is-not-finding-applications-on-windows-10