# Why does Windows 10 not search files correctly?

Tags: windows-10

I've already followed [these instructions](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-make-windows-10-search-through-file-contents/) and made sure that the file types I care about are included in the index and that none of the folders I care about are excluded:

[image: Advanced Options]

I also waited until the indexing was complete:

[image]

**So why does searching in Windows Explorer not find words that are definitely in those files?**

If I use WSL and run `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'someSearchPattern'` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/470749)), I'm able to find results.

But I'd prefer the native Windows GUI to work.

P.S. I also saw [this idea](https://superuser.com/a/950071/74576) but ending the SearchUI.exe task in Task Manager (such that it would restart itself) did not help either: [[image]]

Comment: Two things (looking at my Search): (1) Searchindexer is running properly. I do not see SearchUI (probably because Search is not open. (2) Make sure Index Properties and File Contents is set for each extension you want (.docx, .xlsx, etc). It is not a global property.

Comment: First, try searching in different locations, e.g. search bar on task bar, *Search this PC* in Explorer, etc. They behave differently, sometimes requiring a wild card, *, at the beginning and/or end. Second, Windows Search has limitations that some third-party tools, such as DocFetcher, don't.